# javascript coundown timer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a javascript countdown timer in this type of format:  00:00:00 (Minutes,seconds,milliseconds) respectively. I searched a lot of plugins on the internet but that was not good enough. I want that when the page refresh then the timer value do not reset.
Please tell me the solution or an example code in this regard. I shall be very thankful to all of you.

Comment: If it counts down to a specific time or it counts up from a specific time, refreshing should not have any effect. How should the zero be defined?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple solution for the page refreshing reset by setting the countdown time in the localStorage (as timestamp or Date Object in JSON format) and retrieve it back on a page reload.

```
//timestamp sample
localStorage.setItem("timestamp", /* value goes here */);
var timestamp = localStorage.getItem("timestamp");

//date object sample
localStorage.setItem("date", (new Date("02 23, 2013 13:25:14")).toJSON());
var date = localStorage.getItem("date");
```

So call setItem whenever you set a countdown on your page and on each page load check if there is a previous countdown stored in the localStorage (getItem) of the users browser.

Comment: There are no Date objects in JSON

Comment: If you look at my sample code you see what I mean by storing a date object in JSON. But you're right it is stored as `String` in localStorage but you can convert it back by simply creating a new `Date` object with the value retrieved back from localStorage. `date = new Date(date);`